# Undefined index: sub

Tags: php, indexing, upload, field, undefined

I have problem with upload field. [Error page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scu8x.png)

Actualy when I add upload field to form script gives an error.

The server gives an error for this line: `$filenamefields[$group]['sub']`

```
foreach ($fields as $group => $fieldlist) {
    if (isset($fieldlist['active']) && $fieldlist['active']) {
        $min_req = true;
        if (isset($fieldlist['sub'])) {
            $this->customrule_addrec(
                $fieldlist['sub'],
                $required, $title,
                $type,
                $gprefix.'[' . $group . '][sub]',
                $filenamefields[$group]['sub'],
                $filetypefields[$group]['sub'],
                $filetmpnamefields[$group]['sub'],
                $fileerrorfields[$group]['sub'],
                $filesizefields[$group]['sub']);
```

and this line: `$this->files['size']['fields']);`

```
$min_req = $this->customrule_addrec($fields, $required, $title, $type, '',
      $this->files['name']['fields'],
      $this->files['type']['fields'],
      $this->files['tmp_name']['fields'],
      $this->files['error']['fields'],
      $this->files['size']['fields']);

if (!$min_req)
      $this->addError($attribute, 'Select a group');
```

file codes :

```
<?php
class Orders extends CActiveRecord
{
public $fields;
public $files;
public $file;
public $remove;

public function tableName()
{
    return 'orders';
}


public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'name, start_date, ordertype, user',
            'required'
        ),
        array(
            'status, ordertype, user',
            'numerical',
            'integerOnly' => true
        ),
        array(
            'name',
            'length',
            'max' => 200
        ),
        array(
            'finish_date, desc',
            'safe'
        ),
        array(
            'id, name, start_date, finish_date, status, ordertype, user, desc',
            'safe',
            'on' => 'search'
        ),
        array(
            'fields,files',
            'safe'
        ),
        array(
            'fields',
            'customrule_add',
            'on' => 'add'
        ),
        array(
            'fields',
            'customrule_edit',
            'on' => 'edit'
        ),
        array(
            'file, remove',
            'safe',
            'on' => 'answer'
        )
    );
}

public function customrule_add($attribute, $params)
{
    $fieldtypes = Orderfield::model()->findAll('ordergroup in (select id from ' . Ordergroup::model()->tableName() . ' where orderform = \'' . $this->ordertype . '\')');
    $required = CHtml::listData($fieldtypes, 'id', 'required');
    $title = CHtml::listData($fieldtypes, 'id', 'name');
    $type = CHtml::listData($fieldtypes, 'id', 'type');
    $fields = $this->$attribute;

    $min_req = $this->customrule_addrec($fields, $required, $title, $type, '',
        $this->files['name']['fields'],
        $this->files['type']['fields'],
        $this->files['tmp_name']['fields'],
        $this->files['error']['fields'],
        $this->files['size']['fields']);
    if (!$min_req)
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Select a group');
}

private function customrule_addrec($fields, $required, $title, $type, $gprefix, $filenamefields, $filetypefields, $filetmpnamefields, $fileerrorfields, $filesizefields)
{
    $min_req = false;
    foreach ($fields as $group => $fieldlist) {
        if (isset($fieldlist['active']) && $fieldlist['active']) {
            $min_req = true;
            if (isset($fieldlist['sub'])) {
                $this->customrule_addrec(
                    $fieldlist['sub'],
                    $required, $title,
                    $type,
                    $gprefix.'[' . $group . '][sub]',
                    $filenamefields[$group]['sub'],
                    $filetypefields[$group]['sub'],
                    $filetmpnamefields[$group]['sub'],
                    $fileerrorfields[$group]['sub'],
                    $filesizefields[$group]['sub']);
              foreach ($fieldlist['sub'] as $sgroup => $sfieldlist) {
                  if (isset($sfieldlist['active']) && $sfieldlist['active']) {
                     foreach ($sfieldlist as $key => $value) {
                         if (($key != 'active') && ($key != 'sub') && $required[$key]) {
                              if ($type[$key] != 2) {
                                 if (!$value)
                                  $this->addError('fields[' . $group . '][sub][' . $sgroup . '][' . $key . ']', 'Value ' . $title[$key] . ' Can not be empty');
                          } else if (!isset($this->files['name']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key]) || !$this->files['name']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key]) {
                                $this->addError('fields[' . $group . '][sub][' . $sgroup . '][' . $key . ']', 'File ' . $title[$key] . ' Must send');
                             }
                        }
                     }
                }
             }
            }
            foreach ($fieldlist as $key => $value) {
                if (($key != 'active') && ($key != 'sub') && $required[$key]) {
                    if ($type[$key] != 2) {
                        if (!$value)
                            $this->addError('fields' . $gprefix . '[' . $group . '][' . $key . ']', 'Value ' . $title[$key] . ' Can not be empty');
                    } else if (!isset($filenamefields[$group][$key]) || !$filenamefields[$group][$key]) {
                        $this->addError('fields' . $gprefix . '[' . $group . '][' . $key . ']', 'File ' . $title[$key] . ' Must send');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $min_req;
}

public function customrule_edit($attribute, $params)
{
    $fieldtypes = Orderfield::model()->findAll('ordergroup in (select id from ' . Ordergroup::model()->tableName() . ' where orderform = \'' . $this->ordertype . '\')');
    $required = CHtml::listData($fieldtypes, 'id', 'required');
    $title = CHtml::listData($fieldtypes, 'id', 'name');
    $type = CHtml::listData($fieldtypes, 'id', 'type');
    $groups = CHtml::listData(Ordergroup::model()->findAll(array(
        'select' => 'id,name,orderform',
        'condition' => 'orderform = \'' . $this->ordertype . '\''
    )), 'id', 'name');
    $fields = $this->$attribute;
    $min_req = false;
    foreach ($fields as $group => $fieldlist) {
        if (isset($fieldlist['active']) && $fieldlist['active']) {
            $min_req = true;
            if (isset($fieldlist['sub'])) {
                foreach ($fieldlist['sub'] as $sgroup => $sfieldlist) {
                    if (isset($sfieldlist['active']) && $sfieldlist['active']) {
                        foreach ($sfieldlist as $key => $value) {
                            if (($key != 'active') && ($key != 'sub') && $required[$key]) {
                                if ($type[$key] != 2) {
                                    if (!$value)
                                        $this->addError('fields[' . $group . '][sub][' . $sgroup . '][' . $key . ']', 'value ' . $title[$key] . ' Can not be empty');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach ($fieldlist as $key => $value) {
                if (($key != 'active') && $required[$key]) {
                    if ($type[$key] != 2) {
                        if (!$value)
                            $this->addError('fields[' . $group . '][' . $key . ']', 'value ' . $title[$key] . 'Can not be empty');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$min_req)
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Choose a group');
}

public function add()
{
    $name = $this->name;
    $exists = Orders::model()->exists('`name` = \'' . $name . '\'');
    if ($exists) {
        $count = Orders::model()->count('`name` regexp \'^' . $name . ' - [0-9]+$\'');
        $this->name = $name . ' - ' . ($count + 2);
    }

    $status = $this->save();

    $status = $this->addsub(
        $this->fields,
        $status,
        $this->files['name']['fields'],
        $this->files['type']['fields'],
        $this->files['tmp_name']['fields'],
        $this->files['error']['fields'],
        $this->files['size']['fields']
    );

    if (!$status) {

    Ordervalues::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(
            'order' => $this->id
        ));
        GroupOfOrder::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(
            'order' => $this->id
        ));
        $this->delete();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private function addsub($thisfields, $status, $filenamefields, $filetypefields, $filetmpnamefields, $fileerrorfields, $filesizefields)
{
    foreach ($thisfields as $group => $fieldlist) {
        if (isset($fieldlist['active']) && $fieldlist['active'] && $status) {
            $gofo = new GroupOfOrder('insert');
            $gofo->group = $group;
            $gofo->order = $this->id;
            $gofo->save();

            if (isset($fieldlist['sub'])) {
                $status = $this->addsub(
                    $fieldlist['sub'],
                    $status,
                    $filenamefields[$group]['sub'],
                    $filetypefields[$group]['sub'],
                    $filetmpnamefields[$group]['sub'],
                    $fileerrorfields[$group]['sub'],
                    $filesizefields[$group]['sub']
                );
                if(!$status)
                    return false;
            }
            foreach ($fieldlist as $key => $value) {
                if ($key != 'active' && $key != 'sub' && $status) {
                    $ftype = Orderfield::model()->findByPk($key);
                    if (!$ftype) {
                        $this->addError('fields', 'Field type error');
                        Ordervalues::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(
                            'order' => $this->id
                        ));
                        GroupOfOrder::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(
                            'order' => $this->id
                        ));
                        $this->delete();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!empty($value)) {
                        $field = new Ordervalues('insert');
                        $field->field = $key;
                        $field->order = $this->id;
                        $field->value = $value;
                        $status = ($status && $field->save());
                    } elseif (isset($filenamefields[$group][$key]) && !empty($filenamefields[$group][$key])) {
                        $file = new CUploadedFile($filenamefields[$group][$key], $filetmpnamefields[$group][$key], $filetypefields[$group][$key], $filesizefields[$group][$key], $fileerrorfields[$group][$key]);
                        if ($ftype->file_type) {
                            $all = explode("|", $ftype->file_type); // check every allowed extensions with uploaded file
                            $allowed = false;
                            foreach ($all as $ex) {
                                if ($ex == $file->extensionName) {
                                    $allowed = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!$allowed) {
                                $this->addError('files', 'This format' . $file->extensionName . 'is not true');
                                Ordervalues::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(
                                    'order' => $this->id
                                ));
                                GroupOfOrder::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(
                                    'order' => $this->id
                                ));
                                $this->delete();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        $ffield = new Ordervalues('insert');
                        $ffield->field = $key;
                        $ffield->order = $this->id;
                        $ffield->value = $file->name;
                        $ffield->file_size = $file->size;
                        $status = ($status && $ffield->save());
                        $status = ($status && $file->saveAs('files/' . $ffield->id));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public function edit()
{
    $status = true;
    foreach ($this->fields as $group => $fieldlist) {
        if (isset($fieldlist['active']) && $fieldlist['active']) {
            $gofo = GroupOfOrder::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                'order' => $this->id,
                'group' => $group
            ));
            if (!$gofo) {
                $gofo = new GroupOfOrder('insert');
                $gofo->group = $group;
                $gofo->order = $this->id;
                $gofo->save();
            }

            if (isset($fieldlist['sub'])) {
                foreach ($fieldlist['sub'] as $sgroup => $sfieldlist) {
                    if (isset($sfieldlist['active']) && $sfieldlist['active']) {
                        $sgofo = GroupOfOrder::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                            'order' => $this->id,
                            'group' => $sgroup
                        ));
                        if (!$sgofo) {
                            $sgofo = new GroupOfOrder('insert');
                            $sgofo->group = $sgroup;
                            $sgofo->order = $this->id;
                            $sgofo->save();
                        }
                        foreach ($sfieldlist as $key => $value) {
                            if ($key != 'active' && $key != 'sub' && $status) {
                                $ftype = Orderfield::model()->findByPk($key);
                                if (!$ftype) {
                                    $this->addError('fields', 'Field type error');
                                    return false;
                                }
                                if (!empty($value)) {
                                    $field = Ordervalues::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                                        'order' => $this->id,
                                        'field' => $key
                                    ));
                                    if (!$field) {
                                        $field = new Ordervalues('insert');
                                        $field->field = $key;
                                        $field->order = $this->id;
                                    }
                                    $field->value = $value;
                                    $status = ($status && $field->save());
                                } elseif (isset($this->files['name']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key]) && !empty($this->files['name']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key])) {
                                    $file = new CUploadedFile($this->files['name']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key], $this->files['tmp_name']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key], $this->files['type']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key], $this->files['size']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key], $this->files['error']['fields'][$group]['sub'][$sgroup][$key]);
                                    if ($ftype->file_type) {
                                        $all = explode("|", $ftype->file_type); // check every allowed extensions with uploaded file
                                        $allowed = false;
                                        foreach ($all as $ex) {
                                            if ($ex == $file->extensionName) {
                                                $allowed = true;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (!$allowed) {
                                            $this->addError('files', 'This format ' . $file->extensionName . ' is not true');
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $ffield = Ordervalues::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                                        'order' => $this->id,
                                        'field' => $key
                                    ));
                                    if (!$ffield) {
                                        $ffield = new Ordervalues('insert');
                                        $ffield->field = $key;
                                        $ffield->order = $this->id;
                                    }
                                    $ffield->value = $file->name;
                                    $ffield->file_size = $file->size;
                                    $status = ($status && $ffield->save());
                                    $status = ($status && $file->saveAs('files/' . $ffield->id));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach ($fieldlist as $key => $value) {
                if ($key != 'active' && $key != 'sub' && $status) {
                    $ftype = Orderfield::model()->findByPk($key);
                    if (!$ftype) {
                        $this->addError('fields', 'Field error');
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!empty($value)) {
                        $field = Ordervalues::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                            'order' => $this->id,
                            'field' => $key
                        ));
                        if (!$field) {
                            $field = new Ordervalues('insert');
                            $field->field = $key;
                            $field->order = $this->id;
                        }
                        $field->value = $value;
                        $status = ($status && $field->save());
                    } elseif (isset($this->files['name']['fields'][$group][$key]) && !empty($this->files['name']['fields'][$group][$key])) {
                        $file = new CUploadedFile($this->files['name']['fields'][$group][$key], $this->files['tmp_name']['fields'][$group][$key], $this->files['type']['fields'][$group][$key], $this->files['size']['fields'][$group][$key], $this->files['error']['fields'][$group][$key]);
                        if ($ftype->file_type) {
                            $all = explode("|", $ftype->file_type); // check every allowed extensions with uploaded file
                            $allowed = false;
                            foreach ($all as $ex) {
                                if ($ex == $file->extensionName) {
                                    $allowed = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!$allowed) {
                                $this->addError('files', 'This format ' . $file->extensionName . ' is not true');
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        $ffield = Ordervalues::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                            'order' => $this->id,
                            'field' => $key
                        ));
                        if (!$ffield) {
                            $ffield = new Ordervalues('insert');
                            $ffield->field = $key;
                            $ffield->order = $this->id;
                        }
                        $ffield->value = $file->name;
                        $ffield->file_size = $file->size;
                        $status = ($status && $ffield->save());
                        $status = ($status && $file->saveAs('files/' . $ffield->id));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $gofo = GroupOfOrder::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                'order' => $this->id,
                'group' => $group
            ));
            if ($gofo) {
                $gofo->delete();
                $ovs = Ordervalues::model()->findAll('order = ' . $this->id . ' AND field in (select id from ' . Orderfield::model()->tableName() . ' where ordergroup=' . $group . ')');
                foreach ($ovs as $ov) {
                    if ($ov->field0->type == 2)
                        unlink(Yii::app()->getBasePath() . '/../files/' . $ov->id);
                    $ov->delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $status = ($status && $this->save());
    return $status;
}

public function answer()
{
    if ($this->remove) {
        foreach ($this->remove as $id => $f) {
            if ($f) {
                $filemodel = Orderfiles::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                    'id' => $id,
                    'order_id' => $this->id
                ));
                if ($filemodel) {
                    $filemodel->delete();
                    $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../files/answers/' . $id;
                    if (file_exists($path))
                        unlink($path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'file');
    if ($file) {
        $fm = new Orderfiles('insert');
        $fm->name = $file->name;
        $fm->size = $file->size;
        $fm->order_id = $this->id;
        if ($fm->save() && $this->save())
            return $file->saveAs('files/answers/' . $fm->id);
        return false;
    }
    return $this->save();
}

public function fill_in_fields()
{
    $this->fields = array();
    foreach ($this->ordervalues as $field) {
        $f = $field->field0;
        if (!isset($this->fields[$f->ordergroup]['active']))
            $this->fields[$f->ordergroup]['active'] = true;
        $this->fields[$f->ordergroup][$f->id] = $field->value;
    }
}

public function getPrice()
{
    return Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select sum(price) from ' . Ordergroup::model()->tableName() . ' where id in (select `group` from ' . GroupOfOrder::model()->tableName() . ' where `order` = ' . $this->id . ')')->queryScalar();
}


public function deleteTree()
{
    $ovsff = Ordervalues::model()->findAll('`order` = ' . $this->id . ' AND field in (select id from ' . Orderfield::model()->tableName() . ' where type = 2)');
    if ($ovsff) {
        foreach ($ovsff as $value) {
            $path = Yii::app()->getBasePath() . '/../files/' . $value->id;
            if (file_exists($path))
                unlink($path);
        }
    }

    Ordervalues::model()->deleteAll('`order` = ' . $this->id);
    GroupOfOrder::model()->deleteAll('`order` = ' . $this->id);
    $status = true;
    $ovsff = Orderfiles::model()->findAll('`order_id`  = ' . $this->id); // files of answered orders
    if ($ovsff) {
        foreach ($ovsff as $value) {
            $path = Yii::app()->getBasePath() . '/../files/answers/' . $value->id;
            if (file_exists($path))
                unlink($path);
            $status = $status && $value->delete();
        }
    }
    $trans = $this->trackCode;
    $status = $this->delete();
    $trans->delete();
    return $status;
}


public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'orderfiles' => array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'Orderfiles',
            'order_id'
        ),
        'ordertype0' => array(
            self::BELONGS_TO,
            'Orderform',
            'ordertype'
        ),
        'trackCode' => array(
            self::BELONGS_TO,
            'Transaction',
            'track_code'
        ),
        'user0' => array(
            self::BELONGS_TO,
            'Users',
            'user'
        ),
        'ordervalues' => array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'Ordervalues',
            'order'
        ),
        'tickets' => array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'Ticket',
            'order_id'
        )
    );
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'Code',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'start_date' => 'Date',
        'finish_date' => 'End Date',
        'status' => 'status',
        'ordertype' => 'Type',
        'user' => 'User',
        'track_code' => 'Pay code',
        'desc' => 'Description',
        'file' => 'File'
    );
}

public function getStatus()
{
    $status = array(
        0 => 'Waiting for pay',
        1 => 'In progress',
        2 => 'Completed',
        3 => 'Draft'
    );
    return $status[$this->status];
}

public function getButton()
{
    $status = array(
        0 => 'Waiting for pay',
        1 => 'In progress',
        2 => 'Completed',
        4 => 'Draft'
    );
    if ($this->status == 0) {
        return CHtml::button('Pay', array(
            'onclick' => 'window.location.href=\'' . Yii::app()->createUrl('financial/invoice', array(
                    'id' => $this->track_code
                )) . '\''
        ));
    }
    return CHtml::button('Details', array(
        'onclick' => 'window.location.href=\'' . Yii::app()->createUrl('service/order', array(
                'id' => $this->id
            )) . '\''
    ));
}

public function search()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name', $this->name, true);
    $criteria->compare('start_date', $this->start_date, true);
    $criteria->compare('finish_date', $this->finish_date, true);
    $criteria->compare('status', $this->status);
    $criteria->compare('ordertype', $this->ordertype);
    $criteria->compare('user', $this->user);
    $criteria->compare('track_code', $this->track_code);
    $criteria->compare('desc', $this->desc, true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria
    ));
}

public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You would get more people to look at this if you added a tag for the programming language being shown. It would also be helpful to know what the error message was. Is it just "undefined index: sub"?

Comment: Thank you so much , Yes Only this error is shown